How to enable, on Windows 11, Parameters -> Network and Internet -> Proxy -> Use a proxy in an elegant way through a GPO?
I'm trying to configure proxy settings on a machine in an ad domain.
I've already set the "winINET" proxy configuration by settings some keys in
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings in a GPO
and it works, but when I check Parameters -> Network and Internet -> Proxy -> Use a proxy, it's still disabled.
Is there a way to set this parameter to 'enable', or to tell him to "inherit" from winINET, through a GPO? A computer GPO would be great, because I want this setting configured even if the user log in with the local admin.

On a side note, if someone have a decent link explaining how winhttp, winINET, the proxy settings in parameters, and the registry keys are liked together, who commands what, I'm heavily interested too. What a mess...
